# Deprecated: Return type of PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChang

Tags: php

please help me with an error. I updated my app to php 8.1 and now I am getting this error :

Deprecated: Return type of PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in path

TestCase :

```
/**
 * Counts the number of test cases executed by run(TestResult result).
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function count()
{
    return 1;
}
```

I tried adding #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] in annotations :

```
/**
 * Counts the number of test cases executed by run(TestResult result).
 *
 * [\ReturnTypeWillChange]
 */
public function count()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` FYI annotations do not affect method signature matching. It's more info for linter to STFU once it detects the change. Also you may want to upgrade the PHPUnit version you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the signature so it returns an int. If the [countable interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) is implemented, the signature must match.

```
public function count(): int
{
    return 1;
}
```